# Common Lisp: Hunchentoot: Strange behavior with ASSOC

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols

I'm using this plist as a datastructure:

```
SHALA-SYS> (pass-of (student-from-name "mozart reina"))
(:TYPE M :START-DATE @2015-01-03T15:29:25.000000+09:00 :AMT 17000)
```

And using this table as a reference to match the types with certain numerical values:

```
(defparameter *type-map* '((M . 30)
                           (E . 30)
                           (W . 7)))
```

So using  `assoc`  in the **REPL** works as expected:

```
SHALA-SYS> (assoc (getf (pass-of (student-from-name "mozart reina"))
                        :type)
                  *type-map*)
(M . 30)
```

But when I run the *exact same code* in Hunchentoot I get **nil** instead:

```
(define-easy-handler (dummy-fn :uri "/dummy-fn") ()
  (standard-page (:title "")
    (htm
       (fmt "~A" (assoc (getf (pass-of (student-from-name "mozart reina"))
                              :type)
                        *type-map*)))))

NIL
```

Has anyone had this experience? The only thing I can think of is that somehow MongoDB, which I'm using to persist the data, is somehow screwing with the symbols since it saves them as strings but I run **intern** on them to get turn them back into symbols, and the **REPL** doesn't have a problem with it.

Comment: And in which package do you intern symbols?

Comment: Hah, I just found out that I must have been interning them into #:cl-user instead of the project package... specifying the package explicitly solved it, thanks. Before using MongoDB I was prototyping with a simple global list as a database so that's why this never came up, no need to intern the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a FAQ: **Using symbols as keys does not seem to work**.

If one wants to use symbols as keys into data structures like property-lists, assoc-lists, hash-tables, CLOS objects, ... then one has to make sure that the symbols are interned in the correct package. `cl:*package*` is the current package and this variable may have different values. For example during development and runtime of a program the value of the default package may be different.

When using `CL:INTERN` it is useful to give the package as an argument or to bind the `cl:*package*` variable.

```
CL-USER 10 > (intern "FOO")
FOO
NIL

CL-USER 11 > (symbol-package *)
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 155/256 internal, 0/4 external>

CL-USER 12 > (INTERN "FOO" "HTTP-USER")
HTTP-USER::FOO
NIL

CL-USER 13 > (let ((*package* (find-package "HTTP-USER")))
               (intern "FOO"))
HTTP-USER::FOO
:INTERNAL
```

Comment: In this case what would be better to use as a key? Strings? I opted to use symbols since they're an integrated part of CL and functions for dealing with them seem to be more "native" than equivalent string functions.

Comment: @momo: using symbols is okay. But think of the implications when dealing with uncontrolled input: a program could generate a lot of symbols, because it reads them from input - make sure that unused symbols are actually garbage collected...